# Convert upper case words to title case

Tags: r, regex

I want to change this:

```
input <- c("Théodore Agrippa d'AUBIGNÉ", "Vital d'AUDIGUIER DE LA MENOR")
```

into this :

```
output <- c("Théodore Agrippa d'Aubigné", "Vital d'Audiguier De La Menor")
```

The only words that should be modified are those that are all upper case.

**Edit:**

An edge case, where first letter of sequence isn't in `[A-Z]`:

```
input <- "Philippe Fabre d'ÉGLANTINE"
```

Comment: You are very close with `stringr::str_to_title(input)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Good question! (+1) There seems to be some hate/revenge-voting going on. Answer below is good too; a full base R command would be `gsub("\\b([A-Z])(\\w+)\\b", "\\1\\L\\2", input, perl = T)`.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: No, it's not. One of the worst things on SO is that you are able to downvote without further explanation.

Comment: If you are looking for Title case for French, then you have a difficult question, just regex is not enough due to all the exceptions. Some java script on [this github page](https://github.com/benoitvallon/titlecase-french) + a lot of explanations and here [le guide complet de l’usage des majuscules en français](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/general/guide-complet-usage-majuscules-francais/).

Comment: @phiver I'll `gsub` the "De" into "de" as I'm dealing with old poets and they pretty much all had small "de" (or so I hope), for the "La" I think I'm just out of luck, the 2nd guy from my question is "Vital d'Audiguier de la Menor" but you've got others like "Jean de La Fontaine".

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you showed no effort. This applies to new users just as it does for older ones.

Comment: Yes most of them are "de La" except "Adam de la Halle". Good luck with the poets :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form two groups with boundaries on both sides as in

```
\b([A-Z])(\w+)\b
```

and use `tolower` on the second group (leaving the first untouched).
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gdaEQR/1/) (and mind the modifiers, especially `u`).

---

*As a side note: you still have a couple of questions with (not yet accepted) answers.*

Comment: What questions are you talking about ? can you please comment on them ? I have more than a couple but from what I see I'm not fully satisfied with answers in those case, otherwise i'll be happy to mark answered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as @Maurits comments, the R command would be : `gsub("\\b([A-Z])(\\w+)\\b", "\\1\\L\\2", input, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: Glad to help. Honestly, I keep forgetting the `\L` thingy.

Answer (score 3):

A general answer that detects all upper case characters and works whatever the encoding, would be :

```
input <- c("Théodore Agrippa d'AUBIGNÉ", "Vital d'AUDIGUIER DE LA MENOR", "Philippe Fabre d'ÉGLANTINE")
gsub("(*UCP)\\b(\\p{Lu})(\\p{Lu}+)\\b", "\\1\\L\\2", input, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Théodore Agrippa d'Aubigné"    "Vital d'Audiguier De La Menor" "Philippe Fabre d'Églantine"
```

credits go to [@Wiktor-Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865368/strings-are-identical-using-baseidentical-and-yet-behave-differently-with/51880386#51880386)

`\p{Lu}` detects any Unicode upper case character, the second one can be replaced by `\w` to allow underscores and numbers (would give same output here).

`(*UCP)` is not necessary to reproduce the result here but will come handy if the encoding of the input string is different from native encoding. It makes the pattern "Unicode-aware" in Wiktors's words.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})(\\p{L}+)", "\\L\\1", input, perl = TRUE)
```

I'm not trying to compete with the other existing answers, I just solved (or tried) for the challenge and share it here because it might be useful for someone and/or I get constructive feedback on how it could be improved.

**Edit**

I had for some reason skipped over:

> only words [...] that are all upper case

I think the following deals a bit better with that:

```
gsub("(?<=\\b\\p{Lu})(\\p{Lu}+\\b)", "\\L\\1", input, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: I like it because there's only one group that is replaced, which is quite neat and readable. It doesn't work with some theoretical edge cases see for example : `gsub("(?<=\\p{L})(\\p{L}+)", "\\L\\1", "This and THAT but ALso thIS", perl = TRUE)` but I can't think of a realistic edge case so chances are it would work fine on my dataset

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks for the feedback, I made a second attempt.

Comment: well actually it has almost converged to Wiktor's answer, only that I use positive lookbehind while he uses backreference.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [snakecase pkg](https://github.com/Tazinho/snakecase) and specifically set `sep_in = " "` to not delete non-alphanumerics like `'` (default is `sep_in = "[^[:alnum:]]"`):

```r
library(snakecase)

input <- c("Théodore Agrippa d'AUBIGNÉ", "Vital d'AUDIGUIER DE LA MENOR")
output <- c("Théodore Agrippa d'Aubigné", "Vital d'Audiguier De La Menor")

to_title_case(input, sep_in = " ")
#> [1] "Théodore Agrippa d'Aubigné"    "Vital d'Audiguier De La Menor"

identical(to_title_case(input, sep_in = " "), output)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This works because

1. **snakecase** treats special characters as words, when they are not specified as input separators via `sep_in`.
2. `snakecase::to_title_case()` first applies `snakecase::to_sentence_case()` which separates words by " " and afterwards wraps the (lower case) result inside `tools::toTitleCase()` which doesn't capitalize lone standing "d"'s, i.e. " d ' aubigné" becomes " d ' Aubigné".
3. **snakecase** always "protects" its output, i.e. it cleanes up the messy and probably not intended output separators (here " ") around non-alphanumeric characters (here `'`). (For numeric characters the behaviour can be adjusted via the `numerals` argument).