# Is it possible to write a regex that replaces numbers with that many of a character?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a string with letters and numbers. I want the output to be the same string, but with each number replaced with its numerical quantity of some other character, let's say a pound sign.

Here are some examples of what I would want to achieve:

```
'abc3def' -> 'abc###def'
'ab2cdef5' -> 'ab##cdef#####'
'a1b2c3' -> 'a#b##c###'
```

Is this possible using regex?

Comment: Two downvotes in 10 seconds. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857207/convert-upper-case-words-to-title-case) goes 5 upvotes. Both of them show no effort by the OP. What message does this send to new users?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot do this with regex alone. You can't convert the number, let's say 2, to two `#`. What language are you using?

Comment: Thank you, @UnbearableLightness. That answers my question.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: You could use a perl one-liner: perl -ne 'while(/(.*)([0-9])(.*)/g){print "$1"; print "X"x$2; print "$3\n";}' your_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Slightly longer answer: Regex is tool for reading data, not manipulating it

Long answer:

If you want to do this with JUST regex, you might be able to pull something like that off if whatever Regex implementation your using supports replacement string logic. But, it would make things WAY more complicated than they need to be.

You can however, use Regex to make things a lot easier: [example](https://regex101.com/r/gTb4D9/1)

In the example, I separated the string into a series of matches. Now all I need to do is convert everything that matched the "number" capture group and concate everything back together.

Comment: Thank you! Extending your regex to a full implementation gave me this:
 `.match(/(:?(?<number>\d+)|(?<numbernt>[^\d]+))/gm).map(a => '#'.repeat(parseInt(a)) || a).join('')`
which gives me the behavior I need. However, after seeing your answer, I'm now wondering why a much simpler regex can't be used: `/\d+|[^\d]+/g`
There's probably a major difference between these two that I'm not understanding, although the second one seems to also work well for what I'm doing.

Comment: The only major difference is that my regex uses named capture groups. It makes things a little more readable, and you can pick them out of individual matches, allowing you to test which of the two groups a match contained, if you really wanted to.